# Shouldn't apache specific cron-jobs run in docker image?

Tags: apache, docker, cron

In the [Best practices for running Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/run-only-one-process-per-container) guide it's stated, that there should only run one process per docker container. In Ubuntu there are some cron-jobs related to the apache-httpd which run daily (located in the`/etc/cron.daily/apache2`).

When using the apache-docker-image from the official repository (look [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)) those cronjobs are not run, only the httpd process is started, cron is not running.

Shouldn't the cron-jobs stated above be executed?
I have a hard time to figure out, how one can execute this cron-jobs from another docker-image, as suggested in the "Best-practices-guide" since the "cron-docker-image" should have access to the apache-process in order to run the cron-jobs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For basic apache there are no cron jobs to run.

If you have cron jobs to run there is no "right answer".

If they run daily and only run for a certain amount of time, you could certainly just schedule those to run instead of using cron.

If they run more periodically or you dont have a scheduler that can handle that (like AWS lambda) then it's not against best practices to have your webserver run them as a cron, you would just have to build your own container off of apache's to handle it.

If your real question is "How do I run cron jobs" a quick google brought:

https://github.com/aptible/docker-cron-example

https://hub.docker.com/r/hamiltont/docker-cron/

https://getcarina.com/docs/tutorials/schedule-tasks-cron/

You would just modify those to run in the background with `&` or `nohup`

What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, that's clear, that I could make my own container, in which I could let run the cronjob, but - as already mentioned in my question - it's best practices for docker containers to let run only one process (see ling in questions).

Comment: I mean the answer to running cron jobs in your container and not scheduling tasks as my other suggestion...is to run cron jobs in your container. Are you looking for examples? Your question is unclear on "how do I run cron jobs".

Comment: THanks fo r your help, appreciate it! The problem is not how to run cron-jobs within an container. I know how to achieve that.

My question is more, how to run the apache-specific-cron-jobs from another (cron-dedicated)-container, which is linked with the apache container, since there shouldn't run more than one process (apache2 AND cron) within one container, regarding the [best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/run-only-one-process-per-container) ...